# Learning ajax with MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3 with LinQ and Entity framework and I want to start applying ajax.  Where is the best place to start?  Does anyone have some good detailed tutorials that could help me get from beginner to advanced?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where is the best place to start?

Here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3

Answer (score 2):

I always found pluralsight tutorials very helpful and they have a couple on MVC3.

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/olt/courses.aspx

Alternatively check out this article by Jon Galloway which lists lots of tutorials and resources:
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/17/asp-net-mvc-3-roundup-of-tutorials-videos-labs-and-other-assorted-training-materials.aspx

Or David Haydens blog: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/05/ASPNETMVC3TutorialsIndex.aspx

Finally of course there is always the asp.net website: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post on [Dealing with javascript or JSON results after an AJAX call with Ajax.ActionLink, unobtrusive AJAX and MVC 3](http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Blog/2011/02/27/dealing-with-javascript-or-json-results-after-an-ajax-call-with-ajaxactionlink-unobtrusive-ajax-and-) that might help you along.